# Why an immutable class is mutable in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, immutability

Reading the "The Well-Grounded Java Developer" book by Benjamin J. Evans and Martijn Verburg I've encountered the following example in Groovy:

```
class Character {
    private int strength
    private int wisdom
}

def pc = new Character(strength: 10, wisdom: 15)
pc.strength = 18
println "STR [" + pc.strength + "] WIS [" + pc.wisdom + "]"
```

The output of the snippet is the following:

```
STR [18] WIS [15]
```

Till now there is no questions. The code above have been slightly modified with the `@Immutable` annotation, as the book suggests:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Immutable
class Character {
    private int strength
    private int wisdom
}

def pc = new Character(strength: 10, wisdom: 15)

pc.strength = 18

println "STR [" + pc.strength + "] WIS [" + pc.wisdom + "]"
```

The output of the last snippet is still the same:

```
STR [18] WIS [15]
```

The expected result is anything but not like the one above...

*Why does an object of an immutable class seem to act like a mutable one? Does conception of immutability in Groovy permit modification to class fields?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is expected when explicitly setting the fields to `private`.  The docs for [`Immutable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html) state:

> You don't have to follow Groovy's normal property conventions, e.g. **you can create an explicit private field and then you can write explicit get and set methods**. Such an approach, isn't currently prohibited (to give you some wiggle room to get around these conventions) **but any fields created in this way are deemed not to be part of the significant state of the object** and aren't factored into the equals or hashCode methods.

Answer (score 6):

In order to fix the issue that you reported is simple which is removing `access modifier to fields`. That should fix the issue.

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
@Immutable
class Character {
    int strength
    int wisdom
}

def pc = new Character(strength: 10, wisdom: 15)

pc.strength = 18

println "STR [" + pc.strength + "] WIS [" + pc.wisdom + "]"
```

Now, it will raise an exception, saying below :

> groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: strength for class: Character
>       at Character.setProperty(Script1.groovy)
>       at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:10)

If you want more details on why the behavior is different, please refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7246)